# Excel Start date in range within 365 days

Tags: excel, date

Trying to look through an array ($AJ:$AJ) of dates to find dates within 365 days from today and count them.
I know that you can use the INT($AJ:1) to get the serialnumber of the date set.

But unable to do it on an array.

*I need to find eg. 99BIC and count how many times it is in the sheet with dates not older than 365 days*

Any ideas how to?

```
    A   B
1   Application StartDate
2   1023A   20-03-2014
3   1023B   21-03-2016
4   A5GH    21-03-2016
5   99BIC   31-03-2016
6   99BIC   31-04-2015
7   GRIM    06-04-2015
8   BREAK   07-04-2016
9   SACKTWO 17-03-2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"99BIC",C2:C9,">="&TODAY()-365)
```

for 365 days or

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"99BIC",C2:C9,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())))
```

for a calendar year.

So if today is 26/8/16, the first one would not include 26/8/15 since 2016 is a leap year, but the second one would.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do `=B2+365` or `+366` in this case to account for leap years

Answer (score 0):

Just find the difference of the days ...

```
DateColumn   NowColumn   DayDifferenceColumn     IsMoreThen365
Value        =now()      =NowColumn-DateColumn   =DayDifferenceColumn>365

DateColumn  NowColumn   DayDifferenceColumn IsMoreThen365
20-Mar-2014 8/26/2016 14:04 890.5867301 TRUE
21-Mar-2016 8/26/2016 14:04 158.5867301 FALSE
21-Mar-2016 8/26/2016 14:04 158.5867301 FALSE
31-Mar-2016 8/26/2016 14:04 148.5867301 FALSE
31-Mar-2016 8/26/2016 14:04 148.5867301 FALSE
4-Jun-2015  8/26/2016 14:04 449.5867301 TRUE
4-Jul-2016  8/26/2016 14:04 53.58673009 FALSE
17-Mar-2015 8/26/2016 14:04 528.5867301 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Column C as "Status" with `=IF(B2<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1;MONTH(TODAY());DAY(TODAY()));0;1)`.
Then add an Pivot-Table with the first Column as your Application and the second column as the sum of Column "Status".